# questions on sort array by time in php

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

**---array $points----**

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2011-10-02 05:30:00
                [1] => 20
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2011-10-04 09:30:00
                [1] => 12
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2011-10-01 13:30:00
                [1] => 25
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2011-10-03 02:30:00
                [1] => 31
            )

    )
```

I have an array at above and would like to sort this array by time. Then I used the code as following to sort and result is correct. However, if I changed the  code `time[$key] = $val[0]` to `$time = $val[0]`, the result is wrong.

Is there anyone can explain this to me? Many thanks!

```
foreach($points as $key=>$val){

        $time[$key] = $val[0];

        array_multisort($time, SORT_ASC, $points);
    }
```

Comment: Try this test: Remove the last line (`array_mu...`), comment it out or something, and then print out `$time` after the `foreach` loop using the statement `time[$key] = $val[0]`. Next, change the line to `$time = $val[0]` and see what `$time` produces after the loop.

Comment: This is because of the way `array_multisort` works. It sorts multiple arrays, and when the `$time` array is sorted, the `$points` array is re-ordered according to the array indices in `$time`. The `array_multisort` should come after the `foreach`, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`array_multisort` sorts more than one array at once. However, it works on an array of columns, so the `foreach` loop is needed to get a column of the times. After building up this list, you can then perform the multisort. The `$points` array is ordered according to the indices in `$times`, as per [this example in the docs](https://www.php.net/array_multisort#example-4474).

However, you don't need to perform the sort inside the `foreach`, as that means the sort happens 4 times (in your example). It only needs to happen once:

```
foreach ($points as $key => $val) {
    $time[$key] = $val[0];
}

array_multisort($time, SORT_ASC, $points);
```

Answer (score 6):

The function `uasort()` takes a comparison callback function. You can use this to compare two timestamps.

```
$arr = array(
        array('2011-10-02 05:30:00','20'),
        array('2011-10-04 09:30:00','12'),
        array('2011-10-01 13:30:00','25'),
        array('2011-10-03 02:30:00','31')
);

function timecomp($a,$b)
{
    // Subtracting the UNIX timestamps from each other.
    // Returns a negative number if $b is a date before $a,
    // otherwise positive.
    return strtotime($b[0])-strtotime($a[0]);
}
uasort($arr,'timecomp');

print_r($arr);
```

The above code will return

```
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2011-10-04 09:30:00
            [1] => 12
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2011-10-03 02:30:00
            [1] => 31
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2011-10-02 05:30:00
            [1] => 20
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2011-10-01 13:30:00
            [1] => 25
        )

)
```

Comment: And how does this script NOT add unnecessary overhead? :P The time strings are already sortable, the entire thing you do with walking the array and converting them to timestamps is ridiculous. Plus, you've just invented a new `$arr` structure or something? I didn't find that in the original post. Thanks for the downvote.

Comment: @Rijk This site is for helping, not bashing. I was given you constructive criticism on your code. If there is some overhead, please tell me exactly where it can be improved. And no, I'm not creating a new `$arr` structure.

Comment: Either I totally misunderstood the question, or I already told you. It's in my answer as well.

Comment: @Rijk No, your answer changes the structure, mine does not, so I don't see how my answer deserves a downvote.

Comment: The question doesn't actually ask for how to do it. The OP's code already does it. The question is asking for an explanation as to why.

Answer (score -2):

What you want to do is (basic idea):

```
foreach($points as $key=>$val){
     $time[$val[1]] = $val[0]; // $time will be an array of [ point => time ] pairs
}
asort( $time ); // sorts the array and maintains indexes
```

After this you have an array of `point => time` pairs, sorted by time. To get just the points, for instance do

```
$points = array_keys( $time );
```

Comment: There is no need to do `ksort()` inside your loop, that just adds extra unnecessary overhead. Also, you're completely changing the structure of the array.