# I dont get any difference between SORT_ASC and SORT_DESC in array_multisort()

Tags: php, sorting

My original array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [validTo] => 2017-03-18T00:00:00+01:00
            [value] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [validTo] => 2017-06-28T00:00:00+02:00
            [value] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [validTo] => 2017-11-21T00:00:00+01:00
            [value] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [validTo] => 2017-12-24T00:00:00+01:00
            [value] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [validTo] => 2017-04-29T00:00:00+02:00
            [value] => 3
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [validTo] => 2017-11-17T00:00:00+01:00
            [value] => 3
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [validTo] => 2017-11-26T00:00:00+01:00
            [value] => 3
        )

)
```

I want to sort it by time. Latest time first.

I saw this thread [questions on sort array by time in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715051/questions-on-sort-array-by-time-in-php).

So I tried:

```
// sort arr after date
foreach ($arrs as $i => $arr) {
    $time[$i] = $arr[0];
}

array_multisort($time, SORT_ASC, $arrs);
```

But then I get this output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [validTo] => 2017-03-18T00:00:00+01:00
            [value] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [validTo] => 2017-04-29T00:00:00+02:00
            [value] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [validTo] => 2017-06-28T00:00:00+02:00
            [value] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [validTo] => 2017-11-17T00:00:00+01:00
            [value] => 3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [validTo] => 2017-11-21T00:00:00+01:00
            [value] => 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [validTo] => 2017-11-26T00:00:00+01:00
            [value] => 3
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [validTo] => 2017-12-24T00:00:00+01:00
            [value] => 1
        )

)
```

Which is the wrong "way". So I tried

```
array_multisort($time, SORT_DESC, $arrs);
```

But I get same output. Why is that, and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: look at your foreach, look at the array keys are you are minipulating

Comment: sry, that was a typo

Comment: $arr[0] should reflect your array, you cant just copy code and not understand what you have to change

Comment: @nogad My code is correct now, I just had a typo. My question is regarding SORT_ASC and SORT_DESC

Comment: tell me this is right: `print_r($time)`

Comment: `$time = array_map('strtotime', array_column($arrs, 'validTo'));`

Answer (score 2):

It's much less complex than it seems.

```
rsort($arrs);
```

will do the job.

Because the key you want to sort is the *first* one in the sub arrays, they should compare properly as less than or greater each other than without specifying that key.

```
$a = ['validTo' => '2017-03-18T00:00:00+01:00', 'value' => 1];
$b = ['validTo' => '2017-11-21T00:00:00+01:00', 'value' => 1];

assert($a < $b);
```

Comment: Only if the key to be sorted on is listed first like `validTo`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver `validPoint`. I'll include that in the answer.