# Filter the data according to time in PHP

Tags: php, time, filter

There are different places available

if user wants to book the place he/she will provide the required start and end datetime

```
"needPlaceFrom" : "2017-12-04 09:00:00"
"needPlaceTo"   : "2017-12-04 10:00:00"
```

The required place is already booked but available in required time

```
"bookedFrom" : "2017-12-04 11:00:00"
"bookedTo"   : "2017-12-04 12:00:00"

"bookedFrom" : "2017-12-04 07:00:00"
"bookedTo"   : "2017-12-04 08:00:00"
```

I need to create a condition in which I show the place only when it is available

I am doing this,

```
if(needPlaceFrom < bookedFrom && needPlaceTo < bookedTo || needPlaceFrom > bookedFrom && needPlaceTo > bookedTo)
{
    //show data
}
```

but the problem is that it is also showing me that place even when I am providing

```
 "needPlaceFrom" : "2017-12-04 11:05:00"
```

and the space is already booked from 11:00 - 12:00

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Question not understood. If you want to compare the time, check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8715237/1437261

Comment: You forgot to mention what the problem is, but one that I can see is that you need to use parenthesis to group your conditions. Mixing AND and OR like this is not going to do what you expect.

Comment: it is not showin correct data

Comment: if i am entering needPlaceFrom : "2017-12-04 11:05:00" thn it is making the place available for booking

Comment: @Naruto question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem in condition
this needs to be done like this

```
if((needPlaceFrom < bookedFrom || needPlaceFrom > bookedTo) && (needPlaceTo < bookedFrom || needPlaceTo > bookedTo))
{
    //show data
}
```